# How to extract particular value from Nullable (string) in ClickHouse

Tags: nullable, clickhouse

I'm trying to extract value (which contain email) from Nullable(string), but i don't have a clue how to do it.

I have a table:

| ID | my_array | Nullable(String) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 122 | [{"label": "work", **"value": "xxx123@mail.com"**, "primary": true}, {"label": "work", "value": "xxx567@mail.com", "primary": false}] | Nullable(String) |

I need to extract email addresses from value to new column.
Like this:

| ID | email |
| --- | --- |
| 122 | xxx123@mail.com |
| 122 | xxx567@mail.com |

If someone knowns how to cope with it, please, let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    arrayJoin(
        arrayMap(x -> JSONExtractString(x, 'value'), 
            JSONExtractArrayRaw(coalesce(data, '')))) AS email
FROM
(
    SELECT
        122 AS id,
        '[{"label": "work", "value": "xxx123@mail.com", "primary": true}, {"label": "work", "value": "xxx567@mail.com", "primary": false}]' AS data
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        121,
        NULL
)

/*
┌──id─┬─email───────────┐
│ 122 │ xxx123@mail.com │
│ 122 │ xxx567@mail.com │
└─────┴─────────────────┘
*/
```